# How to mock private object method in google test?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I want to mock the private object method in Gmock. I had prepared a simplified example to describe what I want to achieve:

---

Foo class is calling some external library functions. I decided to create an interface that I can use later for tests.

Foo interface (**Ifoo.h**)

```
class IFoo {
    public:
       virtual ~IFoo() = default;
       virtual void foo_function() const = 0;
};
```

(**foo.h**)

```
#include "Ifoo.h"

class Foo : public IFoo {
    public:
        virtual ~Foo() = default;
        void foo_function() const override {};
};
```

(**foo.cpp**)

```
#include <iostream>
#include "foo.h"

void Foo::foo_function() const {
    std::cout<<"Foo function is calling some library function\n";
}
```

---

Base class is my main class where all logic sits. As you see Foo obj is declared here as a private member (my design decision, tbh I am not sure if good, for sure problematic for tests).

**base.h**

```
#include "foo.h"

class Base {
    public:
       void caller() const {};
    private:
       Foo obj{};
};
```

And problematic (for me) caller function:
**base.cpp**

```
#include <base.h>
#include <iostream>

void Base::caller() const
{
    std::cout << "Base class is calling foo class: " << std::endl;
    obj.foo_function();
}
```

---

My goal is to test Base::caller() method using google test. I did mock for foo:

```
#include "Ifoo.h"
#include <gmock/gmock.h>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

class MockFoo : public IFoo
{
    MOCK_METHOD(void, foo_function, (), (const override));
};
```

And source file where I perform the test:

```
#include "mockFoo.h"
#include "base.h"

class BaseMock : public ::testing::Test
{
    public:
        Base base_obj{};
};

TEST_F(BaseMock, test1)
{
    MockFoo mocked_foo{};

    EXPECT_CALL(mocked_foo, foo_function()).Times(1);
    base_obj.caller();
}
```

*Base::caller()* will be executed from my test so *Foo::foo_function()* also. The problem is that *foo_function()* won't be executed for mocked object but for a real one (since Base class has it as a private data member). Can you give me suggestions please how to make it possible to test and execute mocked function instead of real one?

Comment: The usual thing in this case is to pass the dependency to Base instead of hardcoding it. Here, Base would hold a pointer or a reference to IFoo and the concrete IFoo instance is passed via the constructor or other means (see Dependency Injection).